# How to determine if a TIME is between two other TIMEs when it wraps til the next day?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table has two TIME fields - StartTime and EndTime. My timezones are United States (so range is UTC-4 to UTC-8) but in the database all times are stored in UTC. I'm trying to determine if the current time (in UTC) falls between StartTime and EndTime, so basically:

```
(CURTIME()> StartTime  AND CURTIME()< EndTime) AS IsActive
```

This works for most scenarios, but the bug occurs with records in the UTC-7 and UTC-8 timezones because the offset will often push the time into the next day.

For example:

```
EST (UTC-4) EndTime = 05:30PM becomes 09:30PM UTC, no problem!
PST (UTC-7) EndTime = 05:30PM becomes 00:30AM UTC, big problem!
```

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: "t in the database all times are stored in UTC." ... "records in the UTC-7 and UTC-8 timezones" so not all times are stored in UTC?  or are the mysql clients not setting their sessions' timezone to UTC?

Answer (score 0):

You can add 12 hours to the second time in the case it's "earlier" than the first one.

```
select case when curtime() between col1 and (case when col2 > col1 then col2 else addtime(col2, '12:00:00') end)  then 'IsActive' else 'NotActive' end as result
from   t
```

| result |
| --- |
| NotActive |
| NotActive |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mQeR-tpN)